# Windows 10 booting/disk failures

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, data-recovery

After downloading the new Windows 10 update, my PC completely froze and was unresponsive for 20 minutes, after which I had to force shut down. After trying to boot back into Windows 10 and passing the motherboard/bios, I received the message "Disk read error." After restarting again, I received the error "Reboot and select proper boot device."

At this point, I used a Windows 10 USB to go into troubleshooting and try an automatic repair, which failed and gave me the message:  I then went into cmd:

```
X:\windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft Diskpart version 10.0.17134.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MININT-L7S9GC5

DISKPART> list disk

Disk ###  Status     Size   Free  Dyn  Gpt
---------------------------------------------------------
Disk 1    Online     29 GB  0 B

DISKPART> list volume

Volume ### Ltr Label   Fs    Type      Size  Status  Info 
---------------------------------------------------------
Volume 0   D   ESD-USB FAT32 Removable 29 GB Healthy
```

After seeing that diskpart wasn't picking up my hard drive, I proceeded to use these commands in cmd:

```
X:\windows\system32>chkdsk /r
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

 X:\windows\system32>chkdsk C: /f /r /x
Cannot open volume for direct access.

X:\windows\system32>bootrec.exe /scanos 

Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.

X:\windows\system32> bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd 

Scanning all disks for Windows installations.

Please wait, since this may take a while...

Successfully scanned Windows installations.
Total identified Windows installations: 0
The operation completed successfully.

 X:\windows\system32>bootrec.exe /fixmbr 
The operation completed successfully.

 X:\windows\system32>bootrec.exe /fixboot 
Access is denied.
```

After removing the USB and restarting, Windows booted into automatic repair mode which failed quickly.

I then used an Ubuntu USB to go into terminal and run `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda`and `sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda` so that I could check the hard disk, which came back as "Smart overall health self assessment test result: PASSED" which leads me to believe that this is a Windows 10 problem and not my hard drive being faulty.

Using `sudo fdisk -l` on the Ubuntu USB I obtain these results:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Device    Boot       Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1 *           2048    1026047    1024000 500M 7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048 3906052248 3905026201 1.8T 7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       3906054144 3907024895     970752 474M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.9 GiB, 16008609792 bytes, 31266816 sectors
Units: secors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
```

Edit: I just rebooted back into the Windows 10 USB and used `diskpart` once more, this time with different results:

```
X:\windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft Diskpart version 10.0.17134.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MININT-L7S9GC5

DISKPART> list disk

Disk ###  Status     Size   Free  Dyn  Gpt
---------------------------------------------------------
Disk 0    Online     0 B    0 B
Disk 1    Online     29 GB  0 B
```

Trying to list volume and partition says there are none available.

If I have to do a clean install of Windows to fix this that's alright, I'm just hoping that I can get data off of it first. If this isn't the right place to ask this question, let me know and I can post it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `diskpart` experiment is pretty conclusive. The reminder of what you did was unnecessary and dangerous.

Clearly, your disk has failed. (Coincidentally, this failure occurred during the Windows 10 feature pack installation.) The SMART diagnosis looks for mechanical failure which is not always the cause. A bad wire connection that causes an intermittent signal drop can do this without the need for the HDD hardware to break down.

If you don't have backup, you need to perform data recovery, either by connecting your hard disk drive to another computer with a live OS and trying various recovery procedures, or delivering it to a recovery center. Fortunately, it seems Ubuntu is able to read the faulty disk structure, so you might be able to recover stuff using, say, Dolphin, GNOME Files or whatever your Ubuntu distro has.

Comment: Do you still believe disk failure is the case after rebooting into Windows 10 USB and using diskpart again, this time with the hard drive listed but at 0 B size and 0 B free?

Comment: It is actually a more frightening scenario, especially if it is caused by your little Ubuntu experiment on it. And everything so far points to a damage in metadata area. **But all of these are besides the point.** When it comes to data recovery, one must neither waste time nor unnecessarily test the endurance of affect hardware: Use IsoBuster or R-Studio to capture an image at low-level, on which  you can conduct all sort of experiments with little risk.